# Calculate increase between periods or rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have one Dataframe like this:

```
year    quarter   value
 2000    Q1       10
 2000    Q2       12
 2000    Q3       13
 2000    Q4       13
 2001    Q1       14
 2001    Q2       15
 2001    Q3       16
 2001    Q4       12
```

I would like to calculate the difference between the same quarters in different years
2001Q1-2000Q1, in this case 14-10=4.

How can I do it in a generic way, for example if I want to calculate the difference between 2 quarters instead of 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the number of periods to difference to `DataFrame.diff`

```
In [18]: df['value'].diff(4)
Out[18]: 
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4     4
5     3
6     3
7    -1
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

I would also recommend combining the year and quarter columns into a single `DatetimeIndex`, but that's not strictly necessary.